# Running scipy.integrate.ode in multiprocessing Pool results in huge performance hit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-multiprocessing

I'm using python's `scipy.integrate` to simulate a 29-dimensional linear system of differential equations. Since I need to solve several problem instances, I thought I could speed it up by doing computations in parallel using `multiprocessing.Pool`. Since there is no shared data or synchronization necessary between threads (the problem is embarrassingly parallel), I thought this should obviously work. After I wrote the code to do this, however, I got very strange performance measurements:

- Single-threaded, without jacobian: 20-30 ms per call
- Single-threaded, with jacobian: 10-20 ms per call
- Multi-threaded, without jacobian: 20-30 ms per call
- **Multi-threaded, with jacobian: 10-5000 ms per call**

What's shocking is that what I thought should be the fastest setup, was actually the slowest, and the variability was *two orders of magnitude*. It's a deterministic computation; computers aren't supposed to work this way. What could possibly be causing this?

#### Effect seems system-dependent

I tried the same code on another computer and I didn't see this effect.

Both machines were using Ubuntu 64 bit, Python 2.7.6, scipy version 0.18.0, and numpy version 1.8.2. I didn't see the variability with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz processor. I did see the issue with an [Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7%20Mobile%20i7-2670QM.html).

#### Theories

One thought was that there might be a shared cache among processors, and by running it in parallel I can't fit two instances of the jacobian matrix in the cache, so they constantly battle each other for the cache slowing each other down compared with if they are run serially or without the jacobian. But it's not a million variable system. The jacobian is a 29x29 matrix, which takes up 6728 bytes. The level 1 cache on the processor is [4 x 32 KB](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7%20Mobile%20i7-2670QM.html), much larger. Are there any other shared resources between processors that might be to blame? How can we test this?

Another thing I noticed is that each python process seems to take several hundred percent of the CPU as it's running. This seems to mean that the code is already parallelized at some point (perhaps in the low-level library). This could mean that further parallelization wouldn't help, but I wouldn't expect such a dramatic slowdown.

#### Code

It would be good to try out the on more machines to see if (1) other people can experience the slowdown at all and (2) what are the common features of systems where the slowdown occurs. The code does 10 trials of two parallel computations using a multiprocessing pool of size two, printing out the time per scipy.ode.integrate call for each of the 10 trials.

```
'odeint with multiprocessing variable execution time demonsrtation'

from numpy import dot as npdot
from numpy import add as npadd
from numpy import matrix as npmatrix
from scipy.integrate import ode
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def main():
    "main function"

    pool = Pool(2) # try Pool(1)
    params = [0] * 2

    for trial in xrange(10):
        res = pool.map(run_one, params)
        print "{}. times: {}ms, {}ms".format(trial, int(1000 * res[0]), int(1000 * res[1]))

def run_one(_):
    "perform one simulation"

    final_time = 2.0
    init_state = [0.1 if d < 7 else 0.0 for d in xrange(29)]
    (a_matrix, b_vector) = get_dynamics()

    derivative = lambda dummy_t, state: npadd(npdot(a_matrix, state), b_vector)
    jacobian = lambda dummy_t, dummy_state: a_matrix
    #jacobian = None # try without the jacobian

    #print "jacobian bytes:", jacobian(0, 0).nbytes

    solver = ode(derivative, jacobian)
    solver.set_integrator('vode')
    solver.set_initial_value(init_state, 0)

    start = time.time()
    solver.integrate(final_time)
    dif = time.time() - start

    return dif

def get_dynamics():
    "return a tuple (A, b), which are the system dynamics x' = Ax + b"

    return \
    (
        npmatrix([
        [0, 0, 0, 0.99857378006, 0.053384274244, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 1, -0.003182219341, 0.059524655342, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, -11.570495605469, -2.544637680054, -0.063602626324, 0.106780529022, -0.09491866827, 0.007107574493, -5.20817921341, -23.125876742495, -4.246931301528, -0.710743697134, -1.486697327603, -0.044548215175, 0.03436637817, 0.022990248611, 0.580153205353, 1.047552018229, 11.265023544535, 2.622275290571, 0.382949404795, 0.453076470454, 0.022651889536, 0.012533628369, 0.108399390974, -0.160139432044, -6.115359574845, -0.038972389136, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0.439356565475, -1.998182296753, 0, 0.016651883721, 0.018462046981, -0.001187470742, -10.778778281386, 0.343052863546, -0.034949331535, -3.466737362551, 0.013415853489, -0.006501746896, -0.007248032248, -0.004835912875, -0.152495086764, 2.03915052839, -0.169614300211, -0.279125393264, -0.003678218266, -0.001679708185, 0.050812027754, 0.043273505033, -0.062305315646, 0.979162836629, 0.040401368402, 0.010697028656, 0, ],
        [0, 0, -2.040895462036, -0.458999156952, -0.73502779007, 0.019255757332, -0.00459562242, 0.002120360732, -1.06432932386, -3.659159530947, -0.493546966858, -0.059561101143, -1.953512259413, -0.010939065041, -0.000271004496, 0.050563886711, 1.58833954495, 0.219923768171, 1.821923233098, 2.69319056633, 0.068619628466, 0.086310028398, 0.002415425662, 0.000727041422, 0.640963888079, -0.023016712545, -1.069845542887, -0.596675149197, 0, ],
        [-32.103607177734, 0, -0.503355026245, 2.297859191895, 0, -0.021215811372, -0.02116791904, 0.01581159234, 12.45916782984, -0.353636907076, 0.064136531117, 4.035326800046, -0.272152744884, 0.000999589868, 0.002529691904, 0.111632959213, 2.736421830861, -2.354540136198, 0.175216915979, 0.86308171287, 0.004401276193, 0.004373406589, -0.059795009475, -0.051005479746, 0.609531777761, -1.1157829788, -0.026305051933, -0.033738880627, 0, ],
        [0.102161169052, 32.057830810547, -2.347217559814, -0.503611564636, 0.83494758606, 0.02122657001, -0.037879735231, 0.00035400386, -0.761479736492, -5.12933410588, -1.131382179292, -0.148788337148, 1.380741054924, -0.012931029503, 0.007645723855, 0.073796656681, 1.361745395486, 0.150700793731, 2.452437244444, -1.44883919298, 0.076516270282, 0.087122640348, 0.004623192159, 0.002635233443, -0.079401941141, -0.031023369979, -1.225533436977, 0.657926151362, 0, ],
        [-1.910972595215, 1.713829040527, -0.004005432129, -0.057411193848, 0, 0.013989634812, -0.000906753354, -0.290513515472, -2.060635522957, -0.774845915178, -0.471751979387, -1.213891560083, 5.030515136324, 0.126407660877, 0.113188603433, -2.078420624662, -50.18523312358, 0.340665548784, 0.375863242926, -10.641168797333, -0.003634153255, -0.047962774317, 0.030509705209, 0.027584169642, -10.542357589006, -0.126840767097, -0.391839285172, 0.420788121692, 0, ],
        [0.126296110212, -0.002898250629, -0.319316070797, 0.785201711657, 0.001772374259, 0.00000584372, 0.000005233812, -0.000097899495, -0.072611454126, 0.001666291957, 0.195701043078, 0.517339177294, 0.05236528267, -0.000003359731, -0.000003009077, 0.000056285381, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [-0.018114066432, 0.077615035084, 0.710897211118, 2.454275059389, -0.012792968774, 0.000040510624, 0.000036282541, -0.000678672106, 0.010414324729, -0.044623231468, 0.564308412696, -1.507321670112, 0.066879720068, -0.000023290783, -0.00002085993, 0.000390189123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [-0.019957254425, 0.007108972111, 122.639137999354, 1.791704310155, 0.138329792976, 0.000000726169, 0.000000650379, -0.000012165459, -8.481152717711, -37.713895394132, -93.658221074435, -4.801972165378, -2.567389718833, 0.034138340146, -0.038880106034, 0.044603217363, 0.946016722396, 1.708172458034, 18.369114490772, 4.275967542224, 0.624449778826, 0.738801257357, 0.036936909247, 0.020437742859, 0.176759579388, -0.261128576436, -9.971904607075, -0.063549647738, 0, ],
        [0.007852964982, 0.003925745426, 0.287856349997, 58.053471054491, 0.030698062827, -0.000006837601, -0.000006123962, 0.000114549925, -17.580742026275, 0.55713614874, 0.205946900184, -43.230778067404, 0.004227082975, 0.006053854501, 0.006646690253, -0.009138926083, -0.248663457912, 3.325105302428, -0.276578605231, -0.455150962257, -0.005997822569, -0.002738986905, 0.082855748293, 0.070563187482, -0.101597078067, 1.596654829885, 0.065879787896, 0.017442923517, 0, ],
        [0.011497315687, -0.012583019909, 13.848373855148, 22.28881517216, 0.042287331657, 0.000197558695, 0.000176939544, -0.003309689199, -1.742140233901, -5.959510415282, -11.333020298294, -14.216479234895, -3.944800806497, 0.001304578929, -0.005139259078, 0.08647432259, 2.589998222025, 0.358614863147, 2.970887395829, 4.39160430183, 0.111893402319, 0.140739944934, 0.003938671797, 0.001185537435, 1.045176603318, -0.037531801533, -1.744525005833, -0.972957942438, 0, ],
        [-16.939142002537, 0.618053512295, 107.92089190414, 204.524147386814, 0.204407545189, 0.004742101706, 0.004247169746, -0.079444150933, -2.048456967261, -0.931989524708, -66.540858220883, -116.470289129818, -0.561301215495, -0.022312225275, -0.019484747345, 0.243518778973, 4.462098610572, -3.839389874682, 0.285714413078, 1.40736916669, 0.007176864388, 0.007131419303, -0.097503691021, -0.083171197416, 0.993922379938, -1.819432085819, -0.042893874898, -0.055015718216, 0, ],
        [-0.542809857455, 7.081822285872, -135.012404429101, 460.929268260027, 0.036498617908, 0.006937238413, 0.006213200589, -0.116219147061, -0.827454697348, 19.622217613195, 78.553728334274, -283.23862765888, 3.065444785639, -0.003847616297, -0.028984525722, 0.187507140282, 2.220506417769, 0.245737625222, 3.99902408961, -2.362524402134, 0.124769923797, 0.142065016461, 0.007538727793, 0.004297097528, -0.129475392736, -0.050587718062, -1.998394759416, 1.072835822585, 0, ],
        [-1.286456393795, 0.142279456389, -1.265748910581, 65.74306027738, -1.320702989799, -0.061855995532, -0.055400100872, 1.036269854556, -4.531489334771, 0.368539277612, 0.002487097952, -42.326462719738, 8.96223401238, 0.255676968878, 0.215513465742, -4.275436802385, -81.833676543035, 0.555500345288, 0.612894852362, -17.351836610113, -0.005925968725, -0.078209662789, 0.049750119549, 0.044979645917, -17.190711833803, -0.206830688253, -0.638945907467, 0.686150823668, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.009702263896, -0.008689641059, 0.162541456323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [-8.153162937544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, -3.261265175018, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0.17441246156, -3.261265175018, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, -3.261265175018, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8.5, -18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, -8.153162937544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8.5, -18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.699960862226, 0.262038222227, 0.159589891262, 0.41155156501, -1.701619176699, -0.0427567124, -0.038285155304, 0.703045934017, 16.975651534025, -0.115788018654, -0.127109026104, 3.599544290134, 0.001229743857, 0.016223661959, -0.01033400498, -0.00934235613, -6.433934989563, 0.042639567847, 0.132540852847, -0.142338323726, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -37.001496211974, 0.783588795613, -0.183854784348, -11.869599790688, -0.106084318011, -0.026306590251, -0.027118088888, 0.036744952758, 0.76460150301, 7.002366574508, -0.390318898363, -0.642631203146, -0.005701671024, 0.003522251111, 0.173867535377, 0.147911422248, 0.056092715216, -6.641979472328, 0.039602243105, 0.026181724138, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.991401999957, 13.760045912368, 2.53041689113, 0.082528789604, 0.728264862053, 0.023902766734, -0.022896554363, 0.015327568208, 0.370476566397, -0.412566245022, -6.70094564846, -1.327038338854, -0.227019235965, -0.267482033427, -0.008650986307, -0.003394359441, 0.098792645471, 0.197714179668, -6.369398456151, -0.011976840769, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.965859332057, -3.743127938662, -1.962645156793, 0.018929412474, 11.145046656101, -0.03600197464, -0.001222148117, 0.602488409354, 11.639787952728, -0.407672972316, 1.507740702165, -12.799953897143, 0.005393102236, -0.014208764492, -0.000915158115, -0.000640326416, -0.03653528842, 0.012458973237, -0.083125038259, -5.472831842357, 0, ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
        ])
    , 
        npmatrix([1.0 if d == 28 else 0.0 for d in xrange(29)])
    )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Example Output

Here's an example of the output that demonstrates the problem (each run is slightly different). Notice the large variability in execution times (over two orders of magnitude!). Again, this all goes away if I either use a pool of size 1 (or run the code without a pool), or if I don't use an explicit jacobian in the call to `integrate`.

> 1. times: 5847ms, 5760ms
> 2. times: 4177ms, 3991ms
> 3. times: 229ms, 36ms
> 4. times: 1317ms, 1544ms
> 5. times: 87ms, 100ms
> 6. times: 113ms, 102ms
> 7. times: 4747ms, 5077ms
> 8. times: 597ms, 48ms
> 9. times: 9ms, 49ms
> 10. times: 135ms, 109ms

Comment: Your computation is too small for having improvement with multiprocessing, that is why I'm not surprised it's slower in multiproc. That being said, it does not explain the massive variability of your times. On another topic, did you check if `ode` wasn't already parallelized in scipy? Many methods of scipy/numpy are parallelized, and adding Pool on top of it will resut in bad times.

Comment: @HarryPotfleur You're right that I wouldn't expect a speedup here. The original problem used a larger time bound so each iteration took longer. The variability was also there, although the total script runtime was much longer. I do think you're also right in that the underlying routine is already parallelized (from the question: "each python process seems to take several hundred percent of the CPU as it's running"), although I'm not sure how that would create such large variability.

Comment: Well, maybe if the function is already parallelized, by over-parallelizing it you create a race condition and more process than your computer can handle at once ? You could also check if there is another programm running with higher priority than your python script ? Maybe a routine called every minute or so, with high priority and thus taking all the computing power?

Comment: It's possible, but what would that race condition be? The problem is completely parallel. And why would it be system-dependent? I took your suggestion and checked; there's no other process running which takes up significant CPU at the time of the test.

Comment: Is it possible that your computer is poorly cooled, leading the processor to decrease his computing power to avoid over-heating? If this is system-dependant, the issue is likely to be hardware. Is there enough RAM? Do you have read-write call on the HDD/SSD ?

Comment: I have 16 GB of ram, the processor has 6MB of level-3 cache. The problem isn't *that* large; the Jacobian matrix only takes up 6KB. How would I check the read-write call on the HDD from python? Would that include accesses from paging?

Comment: I wanted to check myself, but on my machine I get single-digit runtimes in milliseconds. My suspicion is that this might be related to the fact that [`vode` is not re-entrant](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode), i.e. you can only have one `ode` instance using the `vode` integrator. Can you try switching to `dopri5` or `dop853` just to see if the timing inconsistency goes away?

Comment: Yes, I only see the timing variation with `vode`, not with `dopri5` or `dop853`. My understanding of non re-entrant is that you aren't allowed to do concurrent calls within the same memory space. Isn't `multiprocessing` using different processes? Do you think `vode` might be using the GPU for computation (any way to check)?

Comment: I believe the "not re-entrant" property mostly means what's written in the documentation: "`You cannot have two ode instances using the “vode” integrator at the same time.`". There's surely some magic going on with global/class variables, and subsequent use of multiple integrators of this kind might interfere with each other. I don't know any details, unfortunately; especially with regards to `multiprocessing`. Did you check, by the way, if the result is correct on multiple cores? If processes step on each other's toes, this could also happen in my opinion.

Comment: 6kb is indeed, not much and should not be an issue. I was asking if you had any read-write call in your code, like saving results or something else, but if you didn't code it, there is no reason to have it.  @Andras seem to have a reasonable explanation though.

Comment: Even global or class variables, though, shouldn't interfere if they're in different address spaces (processes). Unless it's writing to files or doing some sort of inter-process communication (but why would they do that?). I also checked the answers coming out and they are all the same.

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods resources can be explicitly passed to child processes. Take a look at http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html - there you can have process-wise imports...  Off-topic: For your Equation there exists a closed form solution based on the matrix exponential (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation), It should be much faster than scipy.integrate.

Comment: "resources can be explicitly passed to child processes." I made the a matrix and b vector in main and them to each process at a parameter. Is this what you meant? It didn't seem to have an effect (still saw the timing variations)... Off-topic answer: Yes, I've seen this but I can't seem to find a simple formula for the in-homogeneous case (I have a non-zero b vector in x' = Ax + b). Without b I could just do x(0) * e^At... although I'm not 100% sure this would always be faster depending on how large t is.

Comment: I [deleted my off-topic answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l4pcB.png) until the bounty blows over. I'll undelete it once it's no longer eligible for the bounty.

Comment: No, I meant: "...On Unix using the fork start method, a child process can make use of a shared resource created in a parent process using a global resource. However, it is better to pass the object as an argument to the constructor for the child process.  ...", which could explain, that only one instance of `scipy.integrate` is utilized, which screws up the multiprocessing.

Comment: Off-Topic: Looking at your matrix `A`: it has one eigenvalue of zero (since the last column and the last row is zero). Rewriting your problem, so 'A' is invertible, you can directly implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation#Solution_in_matrix_form with `scipy.linalg.expm()` as a two liner. Since all other eigenvalues are negative, I don't expect numeric problems (as long as you use `scipy.linalg.solve()` for inverting the matrix).

Comment: @Dietrich [my deleted answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l4pcB.png) (soon to be undeleted) tries to handle the case of a singular matrix, in case you're interested (and hopefully have more experience than me). OP has noted in a comment that the matrix is user input, so they can't rely on it always having a zero line.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the variability of the execution times you posted for the machine showing the problem, I wonder what else that computer is doing at the time you are running your test.  Here are times I saw when I ran your code on an AWS r3.large server (2 cores, 15 GB of RAM) that normally runs interactive R sessions but is currently mostly idle:

> 1. times: 11ms, 11ms
> 2. times: 9ms, 9ms
> 3. times: 9ms, 9ms
> 4. times: 9ms, 9ms
> 5. times: 10ms, 10ms
> 6. times: 10ms, 10ms
> 7. times: 10ms, 10ms
> 8. times: 11ms, 10ms
> 9. times: 11ms, 10ms
> 10. times: 9ms, 9ms

Is it possible your machine is swapping and you do not know it?  `vmstat 5` will give you a lot of information about swap in and outs, but not about cache evictions.

Intel makes some very nice tools for monitoring--two at a time--thousands of different types of operations and errors going on in a processor--including L2 cache evictions--but they are a bit of a firehose: there is information generated every microsecond--or more frequently--and you have to decide what you are going to monitor and how often you want an interrupt to deliver the numbers into your software.  Likely it will take many runs just to narrow down the stats you want to track and you still have to filter out the noise generated by the operating system and everything else running at the time.  It is a time consuming process, but if you follow it to the end and run many different tests you will come to understand what is going on.

But is this--shared cache resources in a processor--really your question?  It seems more like you just want to figure out why you have variable run times on one machine and, second, why multi-threaded is slower on both machines than single threaded.  Do I have it right?  If not I will edit my answer and we can talk about processor cache, cache snooping and cache coherency.

So, as to the variability on the i7-2670QM CPU machine, I would start with `htop`, `vmstat 5` and `iostat 5` to see if the machine is doing something you didn't realize.  That much variability says the executable is getting stalled because the processor is busy doing something else: going off to the network and not finding a share it expects, unable to connect to a DNS server, getting kerbios failures: it could be a lot of things including hardware failures from a hard disk that is being continually reset.  Oh, and move your program to /dev/shm and cd there before you start it.  That won't help you if there are Python libraries in a bad place on a disk, but at least you won't have issues with your local directory.  Report back what you find and we can make further suggestions.

Your second question as I see it, which is perhaps where you started, is why is your program slower when run multi-threaded than single-threaded.  This is a big subject that will come a lot more in focus if we can see how you multi-threaded it.  But even before we do you have to realize that there are several things that can cause a multi-threaded program to run slower than a single-threaded program, and it can have as much to do with the support infrastructure around your program--libraries and operating system calls you make--as your program.  Just because you do not need mutexes does not mean the libraries and operating system do not need them when they are being called from a multi-threaded application.  Locking a mutex is an expensive operation, especially as different threads are rotated between different cores.

On top of that, since the vode is not re-entrant, if you called it from multiple threads it is possible that it is having trouble finding convergence and having to recalculate the same values many times before it "gets lucky" and has enough processor time to complete an iteration before it is swapped out and intermediate results are overwritten.  Give us the code you are using for your multi-threaded runs and I will add to this answer.

Comment: During execution, vmstat produces lines like `16  0      0 12664772 475440 1406708    0    0     0     0 1782 1497705 24 27 49  0  0`, compared with after it's done: `0  0      0 12717328 475456 1406692    0    0     0    14  165  222  0  0 100  0  0`. The differences that stand out are the number of runnable processes (16 versus 0), interrupts (1782 vs 165), **context switches (1.5 million versus 200)**.

Comment: The multithreaded-code is included in the original question. The `Pool(2)` uses two parallel processes.

Comment: `htop` didn't reveal too much, except that the 16 processes that are newly-spawned runnable are python instances. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hq2IKCM.png). I guess the two longer-running processes are the ones from the multiprocessing pool.

Comment: `iostat` also didn't have anything that looked too suspicious. The disk is not really used. When the program is running, the `avg-cpu` line is split about 50/50 between `%user` and `%system`.

Comment: All of that suggests that your computer has plenty of free memory, buffer space, no disk issues, etc, but there is a constraint.  The context switches and the high system time suggests it might be mutex (or several).  So why do I not see the same on a less capable machine (two cores: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz).  I have CentOS 7, Python 2.7.5, scipy 0.12.1, numpy 1.7.1.  I have not heard of an i7 CPU related issue.  I will try and run it on an i7 machine I have and see.

Comment: OK, i5/i7 is not the issue.  My second machine has eight cores: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz, Python 2.7.10, scipy 0.13.0, numpy 1.8.0 and all of the times were 2-5 ms.

Comment: I changed the number of iterations to 5,000 so I could get a good look at user and system percentage and system stayed at 2-3% while user went to 27%.  Any chance you could uninstall and reinstall Python, scipy and numpy, as crazy as that sounds?  This is starting to look like it is something specific to one machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended as a formatted comment regarding the mathematical background raised in [a comment by @Dietrich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350557/running-scipy-integrate-ode-in-multiprocessing-pool-results-in-huge-performance#comment66277221_39350557). As it doesn't address the programming question, I intend to delete this answer in a little while until the bounty blows over.

As @Dietrich noted, you can solve your ODE exactly, since if

```
x' = A*x,
```

then the exact solution is

```
x(t) = exp(A*t)*x0
```

Already I'd say that an exact solution is always superior than a numerical approximation, but this can indeed be faster than a numerical integration. As you noted in a comment, you're worried about efficiency. So don't compute the matrix exponential for each `t`: compute the eigensystem of `A` only once:

```
A*v_i = L_i*v_i
```

then

```
x(t) = sum_i c_i*v_i*exp(L_i*t),
```

and the coefficients `c_i` can be determined from the linear equations

```
x0 = sum_i c_i*v_i.
```

Now, having an inhomogeneous term doesn't change much, as long as your matrix is not singular:

```
x' = A*x + b
(x - A^(-1)*b)' = A*(x - A^(-1)*b)
```

so we can solve the homogeneous equation for `y = x - A^(-1)*b` and in a final step recover `x = y + A^(-1)*b`.

This all works nicely while the matrix is regular, but in your specific case it's singular. But it turns out that this is due to your final dimension:

```
>>> np.linalg.det(A)
0.0
>>> np.linalg.det(A[:-1,:-1])
1920987.0461154305
```

And also note that the final row of `A` is all zeros (this is the reason for the singularity of `A`). So the last dimension of `x` is constant (or changes linearly due to `b`).

I suggest eliminating this variable, rewriting your equation for the rest of the variables, and solving the non-singular inhomogeneous linear system of ODEs using the above procedure, exactly. It should be faster and precise.

---

The following will be a bit speculative, see also the caveat at the end.

In case of user-input `A` and `b`, things might get trickier. Finding a zero row/column in your matrix would be easy, but `A` can be singular even though none of its rows/columns are fully zero. I'm not an expert in the subject, but I think your best bet is using something akin to [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis): transforming your system of equations according to the eigensystem of `A`. My following thoughts will still assume that `A` is diagonalizable, but mostly because I'm unfamiliar with [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). In realistic cases I'd expect your matrices to be diagonalizable, even if singular.

So I'll assume that the matrix `A` can be decomposed as

```
A = V * D * V^(-1),
```

where `D` is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of `A`, and columns of `V` are the eigenvectors of `A` corresponding to each respective eigenvalue. The very same decomposition can be obtained in numpy using

```
DD,V = np.linalg.eig(A)
D = np.asmatrix(np.diag(DD))
```

I usually prefer using `ndarray`s instead of matrices, but this way `V*D*np.linalg.inv(V)` would really correspond to the matrix product of the three matrices, rather than calling `np.dot` twice.

Now, rewrite your equation again:

```
x' = A*x + b
x' = V*D*V^(-1)*x + b
V^(-1)*x' = D*V^(-1)*x + V^(-1)*b
```

By defining the auxiliary variables

```
X = V^(-1)*x
B = V^(-1)*b
```

we obtain

```
X' = D*X + B
```

i.e. the usual inhomogeneous form, but now `D` is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of `A` in the diagonal.

Since `A` is singular, some of the eigenvalues are zero. Look for zero elements in `D` (well, you can do that already with `DD` from `eig()`), and you'll know that they behave trivially during time-evolution. The remaining variables behave well, although at this point we see that the equations for `X` are decoupled due to `D` being diagonal, so you could integrate each independently and analytically. For this you need to first go from your initial condition `x0` to `X0 = np.linalg.inv(V)*x0`, then after solving the equations, back to `x = V*X`.

Caveat: as I said, I'm not an expert in this subject. I can easily imagine that the inversions involved in the diagonalization can be a numerical issue in practical applications. So I'd first test if the matrix is singular, and only carry on with this procedure if it is (or nearly is). It's possible that the above carries a lot of error, in which case numerical integration might be better (I really can't tell).

Comment: In general, A and b will be user-provided inputs. Is there anything that can be done in the singular case?

Comment: @StanleyBak added an update for a general singular case, but I try to made it clear that I'm not sure about the practical applicability of the method. Still, if I was held at gunpoint, that's how I'd approach the problem analytically.

Answer (score 0):

on my compiled linux kernel :

1. times: 8ms, 7ms
2. times: 5ms, 4ms
3. times: 4ms, 4ms
4. times: 8ms, 8ms
5. times: 4ms, 4ms
6. times: 5ms, 4ms
7. times: 4ms, 8ms
8. times: 8ms, 8ms
9. times: 8ms, 8ms
10. times: 4ms, 5ms

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz

be sure your processor runs at fixed speed, noswap.
/tmp is mounted in RAM.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. At all.

Comment: It is an answer, meaning that performance can be achieved, if your system is well tuned.

Comment: It is an answer, meaning that performance can be achieved, if your system is well tuned. At first, check you have got all 4 processors activated, with command "cat /proc/cpuinfo" (8 threads should be available). in this status check that fixed cpu frequency is used too (2.2ghz) . to be sure your system does not swap, launch "swapoff -a" .  The problem you have is directly linked with context change issues  ,and highn latencies.  That may be related to hardware sharing same irq (cat /proc/irq) , bad drivers... regarding the cpu you are using, there is no reason to have these lssues.

Comment: be sure that your cpu is well cooling too. next, I would suggest disabling services , and unloading drivers (lsmod/rmmod), beginning with network drivers. you may too have syslog issues, some unuseful logs , that are filling and your disk permanently . have a look at "dmesg" ouput, kernel should not log many things

Comment: Note that I'm not OP. I also see single-digit runtimes in milliseconds, as I've already noted in a comment. The question is not "why is it slow", but "why is it inconsistent". That's the only programming aspect of the problem.

Comment: I tried turning off swap and disabling frequency scaling on the CPUs, but the problem still occurs. I do hear the fan spin up when I run the program. dmesg isn't doing anything during the run of the program.