# Python Multiprocessing Slows Down for Solve_ivp with Increasing Dimension While Single-Thread is still fast

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

for an engineering 1D simulation I want to apply multiprocessing in order to increase speed of a fitting process. To do so, I use different experimental datapoints in embarrassingly parallel way as arguments for the multiprocessing starmap function which calls the ODE-system via solve_ivp.
The ODE is a discretized PDE via a matrix scheme. I simplified the problem.

What I am observing is:
For a fixed number of cpu, there seems to be a limit in increasing N (the size of the matrix) until the multi-threaded way is not faster than the single-threaded way anymore.
For `N > 99`, the multiprocessing way is ways slower than just using `num_cpu = 1`.

Why is that? If it would be the dimension of the matrix solely, why is the `num_cpu = 1` way still working fine.

Below is a working code snippet. Used systems are 20.04. Ubuntu on a personal computer and on aws cloud servers.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import scipy
import numpy as np
import datetime


def ode(t, x, N):
    mat = np.identity(N+1)
    mat = np.negative(mat)
    # Derivative
    del_x_d_dt = (mat @ x)
    return del_x_d_dt


def solve_ode(N):
    # Initial Values
    y0 = np.ones(N+1)
    # Solve Equation System
    sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(
        fun=ode,
        t_span = [0, 3600],
        y0=y0,
        method = 'Radau',
        t_eval = np.arange(3600+1),
        vectorized=False,
        args=(N,)
        )
    return sol.t, sol.y


# Settings
N = 99
num_cpu = 12

# Multiprocessing
pool = mp.Pool(num_cpu)

print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}: Started mp ...")
# Execute 10 times
items = [(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,),(N,)]
results = pool.starmap(solve_ode, items)
print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}: ... Finished mp")
```

Comment: There's a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350557/running-scipy-integrate-ode-in-multiprocessing-pool-results-in-huge-performance) regarding the issue. My guess would be Solve_ivp computation is relatively small to get benefits from multiprocessing and over parallelizing created additional operations to handle large number of processes at once

Comment: exactly as @taxevader says.  the overhead of multiprocessing did not warrant the gains in this particular case.  multiprocessing is only likely to be noticeably beneficial when there is a lot of processing to be done...

Comment: I don't think the commenters are on the right track here. It's not a question of some simple multiprocessing overhead; this suddenly increases from completing in less than a second at `N=94` to becoming magnitudes slower at `N=95`.